# how to train a predict in python given this aplhanumeric dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, predict

I got this example dataset, with thousands of rows like this.
I need to train a model that predict the Price value based on the other 5 Values.

Im new in python, and Im using python 3.6 with Jupyter.

in other projects i was able to predict values but all the cell where numerics.

How can i do this with alphanumerical values like the first 2 columns?

then, when the model/network is already trained I will like to input the 5 values and that script return a predicted Price as output.

[image: example dataset]

Comment: Are `Value1` and `Value2` unique values? Or, as with English words, is there a set of distinct values that they can take? If the former, you'll need to convert those values into something useful, otherwise no ML algorithm will be able to make sense of it. If the latter, consider using a [tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing). All this said, it's hard for us to give you good advice without seeing what you've done. Please update this with your code so that we have context.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordan's answer above. Not sure which tool you've used for modelling, but in python you can deal with such cases as follows:

1. If the alphanumeric fields are categories (not unique, repeated values), you will have to create dummies. 
   Refer: https://towardsdatascience.com/the-dummys-guide-to-creating-dummy-variables-f21faddb1d40
2. If they are not categorical, then you must use your domain knowledge to extract features from those columns.